# AUCTeX: how to jump to PDF (with synctex) without recompile when inline preview has been created?

Tags: pdftex, auctex, preview, aquamacs

I'm using `Aquamacs 2.4` on MacOS X 10.6.8 with pdflatex (TeXLive 2011).

My problem:

I can create inline previews of formulas, figures etc. in the source code with `AUCTeX` which is very helpful - e. g. with the command `C-C C-P C-D`.
When I do that, the already compiled PDF output file seems to be removed, so after creating the previews, I can not jump from the source code to the pdf any more (with synctex), but I firstly have to recreate the PDF with pdflatex which takes some time.

So my question is:

- is there anything which I have not configured correctly, or is it normal (or necessary) that during the creation of the AUCTeX previews the original PDF is removed?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

this is a dummy text with a dummy formula:

$a+b = c^2$



\end{document}
```

Comment: I never could get the preview to work, so I won't help you. But I'm curious, why would you want to use both `preview-latex` and `synctex`? Can't you use preview alone until the content is frozen, and then synctex to adjust the typesetting details?

Comment: I find it easier to read in the real PDF. I'm trying to get used to  work more in the source and compiling less often, but in the PDF I get a better overview and I'm not yet familiar with all the power of AUCTeX's navigation and search features, unfortunately.

Comment: I wouldn't say "compiling less often" should be a goal /per se/. On the contrary, I know several places where it is advised to compile as often as possible, as it makes debugging easier. But then again, I'm not using preview, and I understand it may change that experience.

Comment: For me compiling less often is also not the main goal, especially as I also find it easier to find the source of errors, when compiling after small changes, but as 1 pdflatex run for my whole thesis takes >2 minutes, with latexmk it takes even 4..5 minutes .. that interrupts the workflow.

Answer (score 3):

After digging in the customization options of the preview mode, I can suggest the following solution. Since I can't get preview to work due to other problems, I couldn't test it.

So, `M-x customize-group RET preview RET`. Select `Preview Latex`.

Now, you have to find the two following configuration options :

- **Preview pdf2dsc command** : replace `%s.pdf` with `%s-preview.pdf`.
- **Preview Latex command** : in the first string, insert `-job-name='%s-preview'` between `%'%l` and `"\nonstopmode...`.

Screenshots of the relevant options with their default values (in case anything goes wrong):

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, that looks very promising! I made the 2 changes you proposed, tried to make a preview for "region" and it ended (not successfully) with the error `Preview-PDF2DSC exited abnormally with code 1 at Sun Jan  6 12:32:27
PDF2DSC sentinel: Opening input file: no such file or directory, /mypath/_region_.prv/tmp17447LlO/preview.dsc`

Answer (score 2):

The problem (I think, since it used to plaque me as well), is that AUCTeX uses the most recent process because it presumes that's what you are interested in.  However, I am very rarely interested in the output of preview.  I added

```
(defadvice TeX-view (around always-view-master-file activate)
  (let ((TeX-current-process-region-p nil))
    ad-do-it))
```

to my `.emacs` so that whenever I view it thinks that the last command was *not* on a region.  This has fixed the problem for me.

If it really is deleting the pdf (e.g. you can't find it from the Finder), then something is very wrong.